# How to limit process memory utilization on Linux (e.g. using BSD::Resource)

Tags: linux, perl, memory

I'd like to limit the memory usage for my Perl script, running on a Linux system. I've been trying to use [BSD::Resource](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?BSD::Resource)'s `setrlimit`, but have been having problems. I'd appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the problems?  Are you trying to prevent or cause hitting a limit?

Comment: make sure you add the hard limit, not soft one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are developing code, it's easy to have your Perl program run away and consume all of memory.  The machine will grind to a halt, until the program exhausts memory and dies.  You can prevent this problem:

Use this code:

```
use BSD::Resource;
setrlimit(get_rlimits()->{RLIMIT_VMEM}, 1_000_000_000, -1) or die;
1;
```

I put this code in limit.pm (hence the "1;").  I can then say

```
use limit;
```

at the top of any program that I want to limit.

Comment: @alvas: I'm using resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS, (megs * 1048576L, -1L))

Answer (score 3):

[Scott Corely](http://www.red-mercury.com/blog/eclectic-tech/perl-out-of-memory-with-solution/) suggests setting `ulimit` before running the perl script.